# How to disable default Accessibility Action for custom UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, accessibility, uiaccessibility

I'm using a custom UITableView and when I turn on VoiceOver and Rotor's Actions for each cell there is a message: "Actions available" and one of them is delete, which I don't want to be added.

I have read: http://ronnqvi.st/swipe-to-delete-for-voiceover/ and https://gist.github.com/d-ronnqvist/3584ccf3379f9c318e4f which explain how to add custom one.

Based on that I added:
`- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        return NO;
    }`

But still when VoiceOver is on and the Rotor is set to Actions the built-in "Delete" Action is announced.

Is there anything else that needs to be implemented? 
Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution for that? I am looking for a way to remove a default action where "activate, default" is announced.